# export an array of object with ExcelService

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, export

I have this array

```
listTutors = [{
  countryId: 'tt',
  gender: 'both',
  levelId: 'tg',
  sessionType: 'inPerson',
  dashboardStatus: ['notPublished', 'published', 'external'],
  subjectId: 'n',
}];
```

where I want to export it to a xlsx or csv file, So I used the following code using excelService class

```
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {
  Sheets: { data: worksheet },
  SheetNames: ['data'],
};
const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, {
  bookType: 'xlsx',
  type: 'array',
});
this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
```

}

```
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
fileSaver.saveAs(
  data,
  fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getMonth() + EXCEL_EXTENSION
);
```

}

And the result I'm getting is this without the dashboardStatus being exported too, as it's any array field, but I want the data to be exported as it is {here it's empty in dashboardStatus) so I can have notPublished, published, external inside the same column of dashboardStatus.

[image]

How can I achieve that with this method or any other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in demos, by default array or complex objects are ignored while converting to the sheet. You have to transform the `object` before passing it to `json_to_sheet` method.

```
const formattedJson = json.map(d => ({
  ...d,
  dashboardStatus: dashboardStatus.join(', '),
}));
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(formattedJson);
```

[**Existing Demo**](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/example#live-demo)